# How can I insert a record from a table into a temp table when insert record is not null?

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how can I insert a record from a table into a temp table when insert record is not null?

Example:

I have a table call A, and a temp table fall TempTable. Inside the A table contain 1 row and 3 columns:

```
columnA              columnB           columnC   
854111111            854254125
```

I want to insert the record from table A into tempTable which tempTable contain only one column

```
Column
854111111            
854254125
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) the columns into an `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable
SELECT ColumnA
FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnA IS NOT NULL
UNION 
SELECT ColumnB
FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnB IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT ColumnC
FROM TableA
WHERE ColumnC IS NOT NULL
```

Or you could move your `UNION` to a subquery and have only 1 `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO TempTable
SELECT A
FROM (
    SELECT ColumnA A
    FROM TableA
    UNION 
    SELECT ColumnB
    FROM TableA
    UNION
    SELECT ColumnC
    FROM TableA
) t
WHERE A IS NOT NULL
```